# tkinter : how to call a method of a child from another child

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter

It is the first time that i use pyhton to create a graphical interface and i have difficulties to understand the link between the parent and the children.

I first create the root window in a separated thread :

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading as th

class GUI(th.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        th.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.gp = MainFrame(self.root)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def stop(self):
        self.root.destroy()
```

The constructor of this class calls the constructor of the main frame :

```
class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.x=my_label(self)
        self.up=my_update(self)
        self.grid()
```

In this main frame, I have only two simple elements, their class is :

```
class my_label(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.l = tk.Label(self,text="some text")
        self.l.grid()
        self.grid()

class my_update(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.b=tk.Button(self,text="update",command=self.ButtonPushed)
        self.b.grid()
        self.grid()

    def ButtonPushed(self):
        # here is my problem...
```

Doing this works, but when I click on the update button I want to modify `x` (in the `MainFrame`). In other words, I want to modify, from a child, one of the other parent's children... how can i do that ?

Side question : does the general construction of my graphical interface seem correct ? I mean, is it correct to let `my_update` and `my_label` inherit from `tk.Frame` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following: (See comment to see what I modified.)

```
class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.x=my_label(self)
        self.up=my_update(self, self.x) # <-- pass another child to constructor
        self.grid()
```

---

```
class my_label(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.l = tk.Label(self,text="some text")
        self.l.grid()
        self.grid()

    # my_update.ButtonPushed will call this method.
    def ButtonPushed(self):
        self.l['text'] = 'pushed'
```

---

```
class my_update(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, friend):
        #                     ^^^^^^
        # accept another child reference as `freind` as save it as self.friend
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.friend = friend # <-- save reference to another child

        self.b=tk.Button(self,text="update",command=self.ButtonPushed)
        self.b.grid()
        self.grid()

    def ButtonPushed(self):
        self.friend.ButtonPushed() # <-- call another child's method freely.
```

Comment: thanks, your method works. but while i was reading your answer i realized that the conception of my program was incorrect... so i won't need your solution. you helped me anyway by showing me that my i could find a better way to code !

Answer (score 0):

For your side question: I'm not sure what else your application needs to do, so maybe there's a good reason, but it seems to me that wrapping the label and the button in an extra class that inherits from `Frame` over complicates things a bit. I think I'd just do:

```
class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.x=tk.Label(self, text="some text")
        self.up=tk.Button(self, text="update", command=self.ButtonPushed)
        self.x.grid()
        self.up.grid()
        self.grid()

    def ButtonPushed(self):
        # do something with self.x
```

Or if you really need the extra classes, why not have the child classes inherit from tk.Label and tk.Button. No real need to wrap them in an extra frame.